# double flash in texshop preview

Tags: texshop, preview

I am using Texshop 4.44 on a Mac running El Capitan, and I use
an external editor. When I preview a .tex file using pdftex,
the screen image shows a double flash before settling down
and working properly. Is there some way that I can stop this
annoying behavior?

Comment: I had similar problem when I use TexMaker. Zooming out a little bit may help.

Comment: Search for `flash` in the Help->Changes document and see if that helps. Note: it appears multiple times so find them all.